# mongoose model inheritance within javascript prototypal object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, prototypal-inheritance

Suppose you have a route initialization like this required in your main:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  for (var name in names) {
    var schema = new Schema({})  // schema that accepts anything
      , m = mongoose.model(name, schema)
      , controller = new TextController(m)
    app.get('/path', controller.create.bind(controller))
    // etc, etc
```

And TextController is defined externally as:

```
var TextController = function(Model) {
  this.Model = Model
}
TextController.prototype.create = function(req, res) {
  var aDoc = this.Model({   // this is the problematic bit
      title: req.body.title
    , content: req.body.content})
  aDoc.save(function(err) {...})
}
```

For some reason, mongo saves this as an empty document even though the title and content params are the expected strings. As expected, this.Model is some sort of mongoose object, but it seems to be rejecting the save or the instantiation. Any ideas or suggestions?

Note: I added the controller.method.bind(controller) because it was the only way (I knew of) to get access to this.Model.

Edit: I've also tried the following:

```
var TextController = function(myCollection) {
  this.myCollection = myCollection
  this.list = function(req, res) {
    this.myCollection.find({}, function { ... })
  }
}
```

And also tried passing in the name and initializing the model within the scope of the function `function(name) { this.myCollection = mongoose.model(name)  ... }`

Comment: I've been unable to get any answers on this outside of this SO question. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be unrelated to javascript prototypes and completely due to how mongoose does Mixed Type Schemas:

In order to tell mongoose the document has changed you need to `markModified(field)`
example here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed